# Create a Perl hash with an array as the key

Tags: perl

How can I put an array (like the tuple in the following example) into a hash in Perl?

```
%h=();
@a=(1,1);
$h{@a}=1 or $h{\@a}=1??
```

I tried with an array reference, but it does not work. How do I to make it work? I want to essentially de-duplicate by doing the hashing (among other things with this).

Comment: you will need to devise your own hashing algorithm for your array, and then use that as your key.

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: This isn't possible: All keys have to be strings. You can however join the parts of the array to form a key with a character you can guarantee won't appear in the values. This could be a NUL byte: `$h{join "\x00", @a} = 1`.

Comment: @amon is there some reason that syntax `$h{1,2,3}=7; printf('%x ',ord) for split /\w/, (keys %h)[0]` uses `1c` as key separator?

Comment: @mpapec This is ancient multidimensional array emulation (from before there were references in the language). The items are joined by `$;` to form a key. This is *not* to be encouraged. See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24SUBSCRIPT_SEPARATOR) for a description.

Comment: @mpapec: It is the default value for `$;` - the subscript separator. The value was chosen because it is the same as AWK uses for `SUBSEP`. Read about it in `perlvar`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regular hashes can only have string keys, so you'd need to create some kind of hashing function for your arrays. A simple way would be to simply [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) your array elements, e.g.

```
$h{join('-', @a)} = \@a;  # A nice readable separator
$h{join($;, @a)} = \@a;   # A less likely, configurable separator ("\034")
```

But that approach (using a sentinel value) requires that you pick a character that won't be found in the keys. The following doesn't suffer from that problem:

```
$h{pack('(j/a*)*', @a)} = \@a;
```

Alternatively, check out [Hash::MultiKey](https://metacpan.org/module/Hash::MultiKey) which can take a more complex key.

Answer (score 4):

*I tried with array reference, but it does not work*

Funny that, page 361 of the (new) Camel book has a paragraph title:
**References Don't Work As Hash Keys**

So yes, you proved the Camel book right.  It then goes on to tell you how to fix it, using  [Tie::RefHash](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/RefHash.html).

I guess you should buy the book.

(By the way, (1,1) might be called a tuple in Python, but it is called a list in Perl).

Answer (score 2):

To remove duplicates in the array using hashes:

```
my %hash;
@hash{@array} = @array;
my @unique = keys %hash;
```

Alternatively, you can use `map` to create the hash:

```
my %hash = map {$_ => 1} @array;
```

Comment: -1: Doesn't address the OP's inability to use a non-scalar value as a hash key.

Comment: I beg to differ. It deals with his real question (at the end of the post) which is to use a hash to dedup an array. That suggests to me that what he's trying to achieve by setting an array as a hashkey is to assign each of the elements in the array as a separate key in the hash.

Comment: Agreed that it shows how to dedup a data set using a hash, but my reading of the question is that the data elements in the set are tuples, not the elements of each tuple. So, if he can't use the tuples as keys, then using `keys` to dedup isn't possible. Perhaps OP can clarify what exactly he's deduping?